# Wrapping long cells in a tsv to keep them in same column

Tags: text-processing, csv, spreadsheet

Formatting a TSV with long cells with `column` makes its readability very low. It simply breaks lines like this:

```
$ python3 -c 'for i in (1,2,3): print(((str(i)*50)+"\t")*3)' | column -s $'\t' -t

11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111  11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111  1111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111
22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222  22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222  2222222222222222222
2222222222222222222222222222222
33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333  33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333  3333333333333333333
3333333333333333333333333333333
```

My question is, how do I format tsv (most likely csv as well) files, to make sure that when a *maximum cell length* (that can be set with a parameter) is reached, it's not just a line break, but data will start in a new line with the same indentation.

For above data, the result could be something like:

```
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 

2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 
2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 
2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 
2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 
2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 

3333333333 3333333333 3333333333 
3333333333 3333333333 3333333333 
3333333333 3333333333 3333333333 
3333333333 3333333333 3333333333 
3333333333 3333333333 3333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if understand what to want to achieve, but perhaps this `awk` program is useful for you:

Content of `script.awk`:

```awk
{
    ## Number of blocks printed to output.
    block = 0 

    ## Get number of columns searching how many tabs exists in the line.
    ## I substract one because each line has a tab at the end and splits
    ## function count blank space after it like a new column.
    col_nums = split( $0, dummy, /\t+/ )
    --col_nums

    ## Incorrect line if it has not any tab. Omit it.
    if ( col_nums < 1 ) { 
        next
    }   

    ## Get number of chars of each block to output.
    ## 'max_cell_length' is an input argument provided by the user. It means
    ## number of chars to input by line.
    chars = max_cell_length / col_nums

    ## For each column...
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 

        ## This is the index where I begin to extract a substring. Zero is
        ## at first char.
        begin_idx = 0 

        ## Get for each column blocks of 'chars' characters. And repeat until
        ## end of column.
        while ( begin_idx < length( $i ) ) { 
            column = substr( $i, begin_idx, chars )

            ## Increment index to extract next block where last one ended.
            begin_idx += chars

            ## Print block to output.
            printf "%s ", column

            ## When have been printed number of columns indicated by the 
            ## user, change to next line.
            if ( ++block % col_nums == 0 ) { 
                printf "\n"
            }   
        }   
    }   
}

{
    ## For each line, print an extra newline for a pretty output.
    printf "\n"
}
```

Running the script:

```
python3 -c 'for i in (1,2,3): print(((str(i)*50)+"\t")*3)' | awk -v max_cell_length=30 -f script.awk -
```

And result:

```
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 
1111111111 1111111111 1111111111 

2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 
2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 
2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 
2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 
2222222222 2222222222 2222222222 

3333333333 3333333333 3333333333 
3333333333 3333333333 3333333333 
3333333333 3333333333 3333333333 
3333333333 3333333333 3333333333 
3333333333 3333333333 3333333333
```

You can use variable `max_cell_length` to indicate number of chars per line of output (without banks), and I suppose it will be a factor of number of chars in original data. Otherwise output will be bad formated, I tested it with `30`, as you can see in this post, and with `50`. Both seems correct but not with many other strange numbers.